# Upgraded to snow leopard and can't install git from macports [architecture mismatch error]

Tags: git, osx-snow-leopard, mac-osx

I've upgraded to Snow Leopard, re-installed XCode, re-installed macports and when I try to install git I get:

```
:~ $ sudo port install git-core +svn
Error: Cannot install git-core for the arch(s) 'x86_64' because
Error: its dependency zlib is only installed for the arch 'i386'
Error: and the configured universal_archs 'i386 ppc' are not sufficient.
Error: Unable to execute port: architecture mismatch
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer: it looks like the issue is with zlib. I'm guessing you have an old (pre-Snow-Leopard) version of zlib installed; port is seeing that it's there (and therefore not installing a new version) but isn't seeing the right architecture to build a 64-bit Git. I'd uninstall and reinstall zlib within port first, then try git again.

My second answer is a cop-out: try installing Git [from the installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3) instead. (That's what [I was trying to do](https://serverfault.com/q/187475/39440).)